# orientation of div display on html page

Tags: html, css, styles

Below is code that shows three different reports inside their corresponding `divs`.

`Hookdiv` , `keymessagediv` and `WhoToVisit`

Now for the first two, it displays two pie charts. For `WhoToVisit`, it displays a table's data.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Hooksdiv" style="float:right">
   <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 50%; width: 100%;"></div><!-- 370px -->
</div>


<p id="demo2"></p>

<div id="keymessagediv" style="float:left">
    <div id="chartContainerkey" style="height: 50%; width: 60%;"></div>
    <div id="keyMessageChartContainerkey" style="height: 50%; width: 60%;"></div>
</div>

<div id="WhoToVisit">
    <table id="strikerate" class="dataTable" width="100%" height = "50%" style = "position: relative ;bottom: 0;left: 0;">
                <tr>
                    <th id="accName">Name</th>
                    <th id="PrimaryaccName">Primary Account</th>
                    <th id="plannedCall">Planned Calls</th>
                    <th id="actualCall">Actual Calls</th>
                    <th id="strike">Strike Rate</th>
                    <th id="coverage">Coverage</th>

                </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can some please help me place the divs as required in the image below. I am unable to position it as expected.
Please find attached image to positions of the [divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD3bZ.png)

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I am unable to position the divs as required with appropriate width and height.

Comment: You have no image there.

Comment: Please click on divs hyperlink to see expected orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two div should have the equal width so that it can easily fit in a single row. I have given the height of 200px, you can modify it as per your requirements. You can also use bootstrap to achieve this.

```
<div id="Hooksdiv" style="float:right;border: 2px solid black; width: 50%; height: 200px;">
   <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 50%; width: 100%;"></div><!-- 370px -->
   Hooksdiv
</div>


<p id="demo2"></p>

<div id="keymessagediv" style="float:left; border: 2px solid green; width: 49%; height: 200px;">
    <div id="chartContainerkey" style="height: 50%; width: 60%;"></div>
    <div id="keyMessageChartContainerkey" style="height: 50%; width: 60%;">keymessagediv</div>
</div>

<div id="WhoToVisit" style="border: 2px solid red;">
    <table id="strikerate" class="dataTable" width="100%" height = "50%" style = "position: relative ;bottom: 0;left: 0;">
                <tr>
                    <th id="accName">Name</th>
                    <th id="PrimaryaccName">Primary Account</th>
                    <th id="plannedCall">Planned Calls</th>
                    <th id="actualCall">Actual Calls</th>
                    <th id="strike">Strike Rate</th>
                    <th id="coverage">Coverage</th>

                </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```